# wix - saving login\password to connect to MSSQL Server

Tags: installation, passwords, wix, password-protection

I wanna to start installing MS SQL Server Express in silent mode via my installer. I'll create a dialog where user will put the info to connect to Server. There is no problem to remember the server name or username in registry. but what to do with the password? Is there only one solution: to create a custom action which will encrypt/decript the password??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution for encrypting the information by the installer would be a custom action.

However I would step back and ask other questions first.

1. Are you saving the information for uninstall later? If so you could run into the problem where the password has been changed in the interim. It would probably be better to query the user for the password on uninstall instead of attempting to save it. If you really need to save it for uninstall you will need a custom action and you will need to find a way to secure the encryption key, which is basically just as hard as securing the password in the first place.
2. If you really just want it for run time usage by your application it might make more sense to query the user for the password the first time the application runs and store it in either app config or better yet user specific config. You can use DPAPI or [ProtectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) to secure the information.

Comment: +1. I personally rely on point #2 for my installation project, and though it is quite possible that the password changes between install and uninstall, it has never been reported, so I assume it's quite a rare case...

Comment: @Yan, for a local SQL Express DB that is probably true. I usually deal with server side SQL Standard or Enterprise edition with the normal enterprise style forced password expiration as a matter of policy.

Comment: thank's a lot. i'll ask the user for the password on uninstall